# Regexp::Common qw /URI/ not allowing HTTPS

Tags: perl, module

A bug was given to me where https isn't allowed to be entered into one of our forms.  After searching the form I noticed that we are using Regexp::Common qw /URI/

I have tried

```
if ($params{URL} =~ /$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-keep}{-scheme}/)
{
$form{URL} = $1;
}
else
{
$error .= '<li>Website Address is invalid. The URL must be in this form: <b>http://example.com</b></li>';
}
```

and that allows http and https but only saves ://www.google.com into the database

```
if ($params{URL} =~ /$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-keep}/)
{
$form{URL} = $1;
}
else
{
$error .= '<li>Website Address is invalid. The URL must be in this form: <b>http://example.com</b></li>';
}
```

allows only http but saves the entire url into the database

```
if ($params{URL} =~ /$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-scheme}/)
{
$form{URL} = $1;
}
else
{
$error .= '<li>Website Address is invalid. The URL must be in this form: <b>http://example.com</b></li>';
}
```

allows http and https but doesn't save ANYTHING to the database

What I would like is to have https and http valid AND have the complete url saved in the database.

Comment: Try `$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-scheme => qr/https?/}{-keep}`

Comment: I get a  Search pattern not terminated error

Comment: Sorry, you need to use different delimiters for that regex since you're interpolating it into another regex. Such as `qr<https?>`

Comment: YaY!! That totally worked! Please put it as an answer so I can vote on it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The -scheme flag for [Regexp::Common::URI::http](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::URI::http) takes an argument which is a regex to match allowed schemes. It defaults to just matching `http` and leaving out the argument seems to mean the scheme is not included in the match at all. So to match both http and https you can pass it a regex of `https?`:

```
m/$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-scheme => qr<https?>}{-keep}/
```